# Is it possible to have multiple BrowserRouter in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a scenario, I want to have 2 different UI in the existing react app. V1 (versions1) will have a different UI and V2 (versions2) will have a different UI.

Existing implementation is like below,

```
   <BrowserRouter basename=“/us”>
     <Version1Layout>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path=“/” component={Home} />
            <Route exact={true} path=“/about” component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </Version1Layout> 
    </BrowserRouter >
```

But I want something like this:-

```
<div>
 <BrowserRouter basename=“/us/v1”>
   <Version1Layout> 
    <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path=“/” component={Home} />
        <Route exact={true} path=“/about” component={About} />
    </Switch>
   </Version1Layout> 
 </BrowserRouter>
 <BrowserRouter basename=“/us/v2”>
   <Version2Layout>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path=“/report1” component={ReportView1} />
        <Route exact={true} path=“/report2” component={ReportView2} />
    </Switch>
   </Version2Layout>
 </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

> **Is it possible to have multiple BrowserRouter in parallel?**

Comment: Have a look at nested routing https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/2nd-example-nested-routing

Comment: @Drew I tried, But I am getting an error.

Comment: Please do show us what you've tried, and since you say there is an error please also include that as part of your question, it's kind of an important detail/information.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use them in parallel:

```
<div>
 <BrowserRouter basename=“/us”>
  <Switch>
    <Version1Layout path={'/v1'}>
       <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path=“/” component={Home} />
        <Route exact={true} path=“/about” component={About} />
       </Switch>
    </Version1Layout>
    <Version2Layout path={'/v2'}>
       <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path=“/report1” component={ReportView1} />
        <Route exact={true} path=“/report2” component={ReportView2} />
       </Switch>
    </Version2Layout>
    <Redirect to={'/v1'}/>
  </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

The neat thing about `Switch` is it just renders the first component that has a matching `path` prop - you don't event need to use `Route`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use multiple routers but instead you can use nested routers.
See: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: I am talking about multiple BrowserRouter in parallel. Not nested route.

Comment: Nope. It is not possible. You can have only one BrowserRouter. Nest the rest inside.

Comment: Create a main Browser router and then nest versions inside.

Comment: This is just flat out false. `Router` is just a React component providing a routing context, you can render multiples of them. There becomes an issue when you start nesting routers within routers, or rather it's the routing contexts within other routing contexts. The contexts of "outer" routers are unaware of what nested "inner" routers have handled.

Comment: The link is no longer available. Try to write the code in the answer next time.

Comment: @HamDongKyun The updated link: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting